# Facebook Authentication Method

Tags: facebook, methods, authentication

Which authentication method is used in the Facebook login for Android?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth), Facebook uses an authentication system based on OAuth2.0.

**Additional information:**

[Here is the Facebook Android developers page.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/authentication)
Their API most likely just uses a modification of their existing OAuth2.0 framework.